# Repeat the very first and last items while doing islice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, repeat, python-itertools

In the following list of items I want to access two consecutive list items at once and also access the index. On top of that for the very first and last item of the list I want to repeat the data.

```
my_list = ['A','C','G','T','T','C','G','A','G']

print(my_list)
print()


for (n1, v1), (n2,v2) in zip(enumerate(my_list), itertools.islice(enumerate(my_list), 1, None)):
        print(v1)
        print(v2)
        print()

# gives me

['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'G', 'A', 'G']

(0, 'A')
(1, 'C')

(1, 'C')
(2, 'G')

(2, 'G')
(3, 'T')

(3, 'T')
(4, 'T')

(4, 'T')
(5, 'C')

(5, 'C')
(6, 'G')

(6, 'G')
(7, 'A')

(7, 'A')
(8, 'G')
```

How, do I repeat the same index only for very first and very last items??

Expected output:

```
(0, 'A')
(0, 'A')

(0, 'A')
(1, 'C')

(1, 'C')
(2, 'G')

.....
.....

(8, 'G')
(8, 'G')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure your `for` clause and add a couple of `if` statements:

```
for i, j in enumerate(zip(enumerate(my_list), itertools.islice(enumerate(my_list), 1, None))):
    (n1, v1), (n2,v2) = j

    if i == 0:
        print((n1, v1))
        print((n1, v1), '\n')

    print((n1, v1))
    print((n2,v2), '\n')

    if i == len(my_list) - 2:
        print((n2, v2))
        print((n2,v2), '\n')
```